# PHP strange issue with memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I am testing out some memcache code here in PHP:

1:

```
$testInstance = new Memcache;
$var = @$testInstance->connect('localhost', 11211);
echo $var;
// Outputs true no matter if the memcached is running or not.
```

2:

```
$testInstance = new Memcache;
$var = @$testInstance->connect('blablabla', 11211);
echo $var;
// Outputs false
```

Why on earth is this occuring?
I am running WinXP in my development environment and I cant see how the localhost version always returns true no matter if the memcached is running or not.

Thanks!

Comment: may be there is some host named "blablabla" with memcache running around? :)~

Comment: I dont know if I would be happy or not to find that out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue went away when i switched to run `memcached` (not memcache) on a Ubuntu server instead. Really strange...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that memcache is not running on localhost? Maybe it is alive in the background as system service? Put something in and see if you can retrieve it.

Comment: To answer your question, Nope, memcached is not running in the background. I also tried to connect to a cloud EC2 instance which at that time were offline. It did not return false!